# The multi-part identifier could not be bound. 3 table join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

```
USE pubs
SELECT DISTINCT L.au_fname, L.au_lname
FROM dbo.authors L, dbo.titles B
JOIN dbo.titleauthor C ON dbo.authors.au_id=C.au_id
INNER JOIN dbo.titleauthor C1 ON B.title_id=C1.title_id
WHERE B.price >= 13
ORDER BY L.au_lname ASC
```

The bolded dbo.authors in this code keeps producing the error below... I clearly don't understand aliases because i cannot for the life of me, determine what is wrong. I tried changing it to "L" but the same error happens. I didn't think a double join would be this hard.

To explain what I am trying to do here. I am trying to get information from table authors to display based on a WHERE statement on table titles. however they only have common PK's on a 3rd table named title author. There for I am trying to join all 3 tables together via the common PK's.

Comment: What is then full error message?

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The multi-part identifier "dbo.authors.au_id" could not be bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**At one location you are using cartesian product and at one location you are using joins..thats not allowed.** 
You need to use like below- Add join conditions....I dont have ur column names.

```
USE pubs
GO


SELECT DISTINCT L.au_fname, L.au_lname
FROM dbo.authors L 
INNER JOIN dbo.titleauthor C ON L.au_id=C.au_id
INNER JOIN dbo.titles B ON B.title_id=C.title_id
WHERE B.price >= 13
ORDER BY L.au_lname ASC
```

Comment: So I have to do 3 JOINS? I am confused as to what column would go on L in this instance.

Comment: I have updated the answer. I think you need this. Please check.

Comment: that produces an error: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
The multi-part identifier "C1.title_id" could not be bound.

Comment: I am confused as to why this fixed it... Could you explain? Seems like you just moved the variables around.

Comment: i fixed 3 things..  1) you are using cartesian product and at one location you are using joins..thats not allowed 2 ) I removed extra join with dbo.titleauthor . 3) I provided proper alises.. earlier i used c1 but that it should be C. Thanks